# Keyboard issue -pressing any key displays shutdown menu on Asus r209ha after upgrade to 16.10

Tags: keyboard, shutdown

After upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 to fix other problem on my brand new Asus r209ha, pressing any key gives shutdown menu (loc, suspend, restart, shut down) as if power button was pressed. Pressing power button has no effect though. Keyboard is de facto useless now and was behaving normal before with Ubuntu 16.04. Connecting external keyboard via bluetooth works flawless.

I updated latest drivers (I think..), tried to change **keyboard layout**/**language settings** and finally used acpi_listen to check keyboard output.
Pressing any key gave a 4 line result for instance pressing left Shift gave:

```
button/power PBTN 00000080 00000000
button/power PNP0C0C:00 00000080 00000047
button/power PNP0C0C:00 00000080 00000048
button/power PBTN 00000080 00000000
```

Comment: [SOLVED] I am new on this platform so maybe this is not the way/place to share a fix but just now I am very glad to announce keyboard works fine on  Asus R209HA [I think on BIOS also known as E200HA] after downloading kernel 4.9 as explained at http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/12/install-linux-kernel-4-9-ubuntu-linux-mint

Comment: I’m facing same problem with Asus Rog Strix G15 and Ubuntu 20.04. Fresh installation.

Comment: @Pushpendra You can try versions 21+ it seems like resolved

Comment: @ХристиянХристов Thanks :-) But I have sold my Linux PC. And now I'm damned with Macbook Air M1, which is driving me crazy. No buyers ! :-P

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] I am very glad to announce keyboard works fine now on Asus R209HA [I think on BIOS also known as E200HA] after downloading kernel 4.9 as explained at http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/12/install-linux-kernel-4-9-ubuntu-linux-mint

Comment: [SOLVED] This issue seems like solved out of the box if you go with Ubuntu version 21+